# Why does the pitch of an ice cube hitting against the side of a glass increase as the glass empties?

Tags: acoustics, everyday-life, water, frequency, glass

When dropping several ice cubes into a full glass of water, I've noticed that the pitch of the cubes hitting against the side of the glass is much lower than if the glass contains less water - the less liquid is in the glass, the higher pitched the ice cubes sound when hitting against the side. Why is this the case?